# TEAMS Connector to Facebook Workplace

Tags: microsoft-teams, sharepoint-online, power-automate, power-platform, facebook-workplace

I am looking to connect TEAMS channel posting with Facebook Workplace posting. The requirement is to copy over the Facebook posting to a specific TEAMS channel. The copy will include the text write up, links and pictures/videos in the Facebook post.

Is this possible to be done through TEAMS connectors? If copy from Facebook Workplace to TEAMS is not possible, what about the other way round? That is copy from TEAMS posting to Facebook Workplace.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Incoming Webhook** you can copy the Facebook posting to a specific TEAMS channel.

Using Incoming webhook connector you can send the adaptive card. This card is highly customizable and can contain any combination of text, speech, images, buttons, and input fields.

Reference Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-incoming-webhook

Comment: No this does not resolve my need.

Comment: Using Incoming webhook connector you can send the adaptive card. This card is highly customizable and can contain any combination of text, speech, images, buttons, and input fields.